# The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined. How to fix in ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined
This environment variable is needed to run this program.

How to fix in ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: which command did you type to get this error? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably more a question for http://ubuntuforums.org/

That said, you can do:

export JAVA_HOME='path/to/your/java/installation'

and add the same line to your .bashrc file to have it done every time you log in.

Beware, usually if you install java using apt-get, you should not have to set the java_home environmnent variable.